# How to get users with specific roles with their profile details in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get users with customer's role only along with their profile details in laravel. my query is like this

```
    $customer = User::with(['roles' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('name', '=', 'customer');
                }])->join('profiles', 'profiles.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->join('cities', 'cities.id', '=', 'profiles.city')
                ->where([['users.email', 'LIKE', '%'.$email.'%'], ['profiles.mobile', 'LIKE', '%'.$mobile.'%'], ['profiles.name', 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%'], ['cities.name', 'LIKE', '%'.$city.'%'], ['profiles.home_address', 'LIKE', '%'.$address.'%']])
                ->select('profiles.name','profiles.mobile','profiles.home_address','cities.name as city', 'users.id','users.email')
                ->orderBy($sort_field, $sort_type)
                ->paginate($pagination);
```

But i am getting all role's records.

Can anyone help or look at this.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: add you db structure as well

Comment: Yes it would be nice to have a gist (https://gist.github.com for example) with your migrations or to add it on your first post so that we would be able to try on our computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below Code is working

```
$customer = User::whereHas(
        'roles', function($q){
        $q->where('name', 'customer');
        }
        )->join('profiles', 'profiles.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->join('cities', 'cities.id', '=', 'profiles.city')
            ->where([['users.email', 'LIKE', '%'.$email.'%'], ['profiles.mobile', 'LIKE', '%'.$mobile.'%'], ['profiles.name', 'LIKE', '%'.$name.'%'], ['cities.name', 'LIKE', '%'.$city.'%'], ['profiles.home_address', 'LIKE', '%'.$address.'%']])
            ->select('profiles.name','profiles.mobile','profiles.home_address','cities.name as city', 'users.id','users.email')
            ->orderBy($sort_field, $sort_type)
            ->paginate($pagination);
```